# Number of elements in Periodic Table shows up as 0 and not 118

Tags: java, arrays

I need to output the number of elements from a dat file. The number of elements needs to be 118 but I get 0.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PeriodicTable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 128;

        int[] atomicNumber = new int[MAX_ELEMENTS];
        File file = new File("periodictable.dat");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int currentElements = 0;

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            atomicNumber[currentElements] = inputFile.nextInt();
            String symbol = inputFile.next();
            float mass = inputFile.nextFloat();
            String name = inputFile.next();
            currentElements++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        System.out.println("Periodic Table\n");
        System.out.println(currentElements + " elements");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: print the elements you read, you'll quickly see what's wrong

Comment: Just tested this code with some test data and it was correctly returning the total number of sets of data, in my case `38` was printed because I made 38 sets of data that contained the format of `int String float String` on 38 different lines (although your code will work with everything on a single line).  Looks like your input data is not accurate to what you programmed.

Comment: Is your code actually printing `"0 elements"` (in which case your file is empty), or is it throwing some kind of exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the sample class it seems to work correctly for me, so I assume there is and issue with the `periodictable.dat` file.

With a test `periodictable.dat` file filled with the following:

`110 T 200.00 Test
300 A 100.18 Again`

I get the following output:

`Periodic Table
2 elements`

If there was a formatting error in the file you would receive a mismatch exception. So I would

- Check your file is not empty as this would cause the while condition to be false.
- I would also add what your current file looks like in your question :)